# Override Maven Plugin Parameters

Tags: maven

I have a Maven plugin and it is configured in the POM file as

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <scriptsPath>scripts</scriptsPath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now I want to override that `scriptsPath` from from command line so I run

```
mvn -X example-maven-plugin:goal -DscriptsPath=scripts1
```

I can see that value of the `scriptsPath` is still `scripts` and not `scripts1`. Could the configuration parameter be overriden from the command line ?

Comment: it could, but it depends on the maven plugin implementation (and support) for it and whether it applies the same name as the xml element name (which is not always the case). To be checked on the plugin official documentation, if any

Comment: If `example-maven-plugin` supports command line parameters, you can see their names by running `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=example-maven-plugin:goal -Ddetail`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no general way to override maven plugin configuration by using properties. If the plugin documentation does not explicitly allow you to use a property to set the configuration value you can use following pattern:

```
<properties>
    <scripts.path>scripts</scripts.path>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <scriptsPath>${scripts.path}</scriptsPath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and then execute maven as

```
mvn -X example-maven-plugin:goal -Dscripts.path=scripts1
```

Comment: That's exactly what the linked duplicate is answering. You should flag as duplicate instead.

Comment: Well, it uses the same approach. However, in the linked answer, it is the `<version>` what is set through a property, which may look like an answer to a different question to unexperienced maven users. That is why I answered his question without marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it is a duplicate. and @StepanVavra approach is the one that works.

Comment: @Tunaki the other question isn't too useful for someone looking to solve this issue (longer than it needs to be, overwrite instead of override, no pom given in the question) and is quite different, ie how to override a property vs how to override a configuration. and stephan's answer is perfect - he gives the factually correct answer ("no general way"), and a workaround using properties